# How to create a virtual directory for web server? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, web

I hope someone can help.

I'd like to create a virtualDirectory for a site with say the following directories
host/folder1/folder2/default.aspx on a web server.

With IIS this can be easily done by editing the applicationHost.config file:

```
<application path="/">
 <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
</application>
```

..but when I try the same method and upload the config file to the root level of the webserver and type the virtual path, I get a 404b error.

I don't want to always type the full path, instead just want something short like host/default.aspx while keeping the files in their current directory.

How is this done for a web server?

Hope my problem makes sense.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply Full information for your Site.  the critical information is Port number ,site name and  id itself(remove any duplicates). following example i mentioned it as  "MySite", 2, 8080 respectively.

```
            <sites>
               <site name="MySite" id="2">
                  <application path="/">
                     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
                  </application>
                  <bindings>
                     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:" />
                  </bindings>
               </site>

               <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
               <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
            </sites>
```

Same can be done in C#

```
            using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

    using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
          {
             Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
             ConfigurationSection sitesSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites");
             ConfigurationElementCollection sitesCollection = sitesSection.GetCollection();

             ConfigurationElement siteElement = sitesCollection.CreateElement("site");
             siteElement["name"] = @"MySite";
             siteElement["id"] = 2;
             siteElement["serverAutoStart"] = true;

             ConfigurationElementCollection bindingsCollection = siteElement.GetCollection("bindings");
             ConfigurationElement bindingElement = bindingsCollection.CreateElement("binding");
             bindingElement["protocol"] = @"http";
             bindingElement["bindingInformation"] = @"*:8080:www.MySite.com";
             bindingsCollection.Add(bindingElement);

             ConfigurationElementCollection siteCollection = siteElement.GetCollection();
             ConfigurationElement applicationElement = siteCollection.CreateElement("application");
             applicationElement["path"] = @"/";
             ConfigurationElementCollection applicationCollection = applicationElement.GetCollection();
             ConfigurationElement virtualDirectoryElement = applicationCollection.CreateElement("virtualDirectory");
             virtualDirectoryElement["path"] = @"/";
             virtualDirectoryElement["physicalPath"] = @"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot";
             applicationCollection.Add(virtualDirectoryElement);
             siteCollection.Add(applicationElement);
             sitesCollection.Add(siteElement);

             serverManager.CommitChanges();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what your trying to accomplish but you can use the Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace for setting up IIS through code.

[Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)